# multilingual tables - are composite keys the way to go?

Tags: sql, composite-primary-key

There's bunch of items that require translations, and I have three tables. `Languages`, `Fruits` and `FruitNames`

this is the code I would use (in ms SQL)

```
CREATE TABLE [FruitNames] (
    [LanguageId] INT NOT NULL ,
    [FruitId] INT NOT NULL ,
    [name] NVARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (LanguageId) REFERENCES Languages(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (FruitId) REFERENCES Fruits(id),
    PRIMARY KEY ([LanguageId],[FruitId])
)
```

Assuming that I will never require two names of the same language for one item, Is there an advantage to using a composite key?

Comment: There could be a fruit description as-well, I'd put it into the same table as long as there is only one.

Comment: a fruit category (many-to-many) (the category would be translated similarly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a pretty good candidate for a composite key to me.  I can't speak for overall scalability, but if all you're translating is the fruit's name, this should be fine.

Comment: @climbage: oh, I missed that. I read the table description several times and didn't see that. * went for glasses

Comment: @zerkms haha phew.  you had me questioning my sanity